# Why does git hash-object output different hash between termminals?

Tags: git

On my machine, if I open a windows command prompt, git bash prompt and powershell terminal and type:

```
echo "Apple Pie" | git hash-object --stdin
```

I get a different hash in each window. If I close all of the windows, reopen them all again and repeat the command in each again, each terminal returns the same hash that it did previously.

Shouldn't the hash be the same no matter where this command is run?

Also, `running git --version` says that all of the three prompts are all using the same version of git (I only have one installed anyways).

Comment: I will bet that in one window, `echo` terminates lines with a linefeed (unix style), while in the other window, `echo` terminates lines with a carriage return/linefeed pair (dos style). Because you're passing different content to `git hash-object`, you get different results.

Comment: All three terminals a re different though. Do you think they all do it differently?

Comment: Don't guess, test it out! Pipe the output of `echo` into a hex dump tool (like `od -x ` or something else) and verify the content. Or point `git hash-object` *at the same file* so you *know* you're feeding each invocation the same content.

Comment: PowerShell is a ... unique beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you're hashing in each case is different.

In Git Bash, you're hashing `Apple Pie\n`; that is, the data is terminated with a LF, the Unix line ending.  In CMD, you're hashing `Apple Pie\r\n`, with a CRLF, the Windows line ending.

For PowerShell, anything you put through a pipe is turned into little-endian UTF-16 with a byte order mark and CRLF endings, so you're hashing that instead.  `git hash-object` works the same in every case, but the bytes you're passing to it are different.

If you want reproducible data, don't use `echo`.  Use `printf`, which doesn't automatically add a newline.  In addition, if you don't want your data to be converted, don't pass it through a pipe in PowerShell.  Pipes in PowerShell always force things to its internal text format and are not binary safe, so I recommend avoiding PowerShell anytime you'd like to use a pipe.